# Making an HTML game-ish thing

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm using Notepad++ with HTML and javascript to try and make a little clicker game (Similar to cookie clicker if you've ever played it) and I'm just using it to experiment with stuff. I have a uneditable text field and a button that when clicked adds "1" to the value of the textfield. I've been trying to create another button that simply checks for a value greater or equal to five in the text field, then subtract five if it's true. (The ultimate goal is to have three buttons -- One that when clicked checks for a value greater than five, then subtracts five, which makes another button that wasn't clickable become clickable, which will add 10 to the value when clicked kind of like an upgrade.)

I've got the button to add +1 to the value, and I've been trying to get the upgrade one to enable a disabled button. But for some reason the button won't work..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Button Clicker</title>
    <script language="Javascript">
function handleButtonClick() {
    var textField = document.getElementById( "textField" );
    var currentValue = parseInt(textField.value);

    // Add one
    currentValue = currentValue + 1;

    // Put it back with the new +1'd value
    textField.value = currentValue;
}
function handlebuttonclick() {
    var textField = document.getElementById( "textField" );
    var currentValue = parseInt(textField.value);

    // Minus one
    currentValue = currentValue - 1;

    // Put it back with the new -1'd value
    textField.value = currentValue;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>



<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">  
 function enable(){  
  if (document.form="upgrade".clicked==''){  
   document.agreement_form.clicker.disabled=true  
  }else{  
   document.agreement_form.clicker.disabled=false  
  }  
 }  
</script>

 <button type="button" form="upgrade" onclick="enable()" onclick="handlebuttonclick"/>Upgrade</button>
 <br>
 <button type="button" onClick="handleButtonClick()"/>Press here</button>
 <input type="button" value="Clicker" disabled name="clicker"> 

<input type="text" value="0" id="textField" readonly/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and the question is...?

Comment: You know I could just edit the DOM, make the text field editable, and change it to 9999999999999, right? :p You'll have to do a little better to make a game like this. Cookie Clicker recognises this and even gives you a Shadow Achievement for hacking cookies.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please provide some code and details as to what you have tried and exactly what your issue is so SO members can properly address it.

Comment: Facebook, twitter etc. are for status updates on what you’re doing – this site is for actual _questions_ … but you did not ask one.

Comment: I was asking on "how" to make this work. And Bronx, I stated I made the text field uneditable. Currently it's not working, because I'm thoroughly confused.

Comment: @ZackUnisaki Your code is confusing me just as much. `document.agreement_form` -> there is no `agreement_form` in your HTML code. And even when, better use `document.getElementById()` to select a HTML node. `onclick="enable()" onclick="handlebuttonclick"`-> which one is it? `if (document.form="upgrade".clicked=='')` what is that supposed to do? Is that even valid syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the bug:

```
<button type="button" form="upgrade" onclick="enable()" onclick="handlebuttonclick"/>Upgrade</button>
                                        ^                   ^
                                        |                   |
                                         \                 /
                                          \               /
                                           \             /
                                            \           /
                                 you can't have two onclick handlers
```

The solution is to simply call both functions in the onclick handler:

```
onclick="enable();handlebuttonclick()"
```

Or even call `enable` from inside `handlebuttonclick`:

```
function handlebuttonclick() {

    // ..... bunch of code    

    enable();
}
```

---

### BTW, some advice:

Try not to confuse yourself by declaring variables and functions with similar names (`handlebuttonclick` vs `handleButtonClick`). Just because it works doesn't mean it's "correct". The primary function of source code is to document your intentions. Making the code execute on a computer is actually a secondary function. Give your functions meaningful names:

```
<button id='increment' onclick='handle_increment()'> + </button>
<button id='decrement' onclick='handle_decrement();enable()'> - </button>
```

Secondly, and this is minor but since it means less typing and cleaner code it's good to follow: `language="javascript"` is deprecated and I believe is invalid for HTML5 (which is your DOCTYPE) and `type="text/javascript"` is unnecessary for HTML5. So just write

```
<script>
    // javascript code...
</script>
```

Thirdly, self-closing tags like `<input ... />` is xHTML and is invalid HTML5 (though browsers will tolerate it, potentially triggering quirks mode (quirks mode is a mode where the browser tries to emulate previous bugs)). Also, you've incorrectly self-closed the `<button>` tag. The `/>` at the end of the tag has the same meaning as closing the tag with a `</...>` tag. So:

```
<button />
```

means the same as

```
<button></button>
```

Therefore, `<button /></button>` is invalid.

But that's moot anyway since this is html5 and not xhtml - don't use the `/>`.

There are lots of other things that can be improved such as assigning onclick handler in javascript rather than HTML etc. but they're not strictly "wrong", they're more a matter of style.